# How to search name referenceBlock and referenceContainer in magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2

I want custom my theme but when use name=" name class html " it do not working. Please help me
[image]

My Code: default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.actions" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attribute" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.detailed" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="page.title.wrapper.product" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" display="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mystoretheme-logo.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: you should redeploy static contents to make your changes work

Comment: i can't search name :(

Comment: static:upgrade and deploy but it not working :(

Comment: post your codes so others can check as well

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: what do you want , I mean what do you mean by search name?

Comment: oh no, i want search it in vendor, because i want custom them

Comment: what you  mean by `name class html`

Comment: did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can go to:

> app → design → frontend → Vendor → Theme → Magento_Theme → layout → **default.xml**

But if you want to check it through the vendor, it is located at path:

> vendor > magento > module-theme > view > frontend > layout > **default.xml**